# PHP/MySQL Update checkbox selection to database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a database field with a 1 or 0, depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

It seems to work when the checkbox is checked but not when empty.

Any ideas how to solve this? Code below. Many Thanks, S.

Here's the code within my form:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM istable WHERE assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);              
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {                                           
        echo '<li>                          
                <label for="changePP'.$row['id'].'"><input id="changePP'.$row['id'].'" type="checkbox" name="showPP_ids[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"'.($row['showPP']=='1' ? ' checked="checked"':NULL).' /> Display</label>
                </li>'. PHP_EOL;                                        
        }
```

And the php process code (updated):

```
$newQuery=mysql_query("select * from ispdfs where assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'");
    $newResult=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);    

    foreach ($newResult as $showPP_ids) {
      $val = (int) isset($_POST['showPP_ids']); 
        mysql_query("UPDATE ispdfs SET showPP = $val WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($showPP_ids));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have nothing here that sets the values to zero.  Boxes that are not checked will simply be absent from the $_POST array.

You'll need to make a separate list of the names of all of the checkboxes and cycle through those, comparing them against the $_POST array.

**Edit:** Wasn't going to write any code, but:

```
$allids = array('id1','id2','id3');

foreach ($allids as $oneid) {
  $val = (int) isset($_POST[$oneid]);  // will be 0 or 1
  mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = $val WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($oneid));
}
```

Note that we don't really need the mysql_real_escape_string here since we know that all the id values are safe, but it's good practice just in case someone comes along later and carelessly changes the $allids array.

**Edit again:** Suppose we don't know what ids to look for.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = 0");
foreach ($_POST as $oneid=>$nothing) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = 1 WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($oneid));
}
```

Comment: This works if you know the fieldnames beforehand. Combine this method with your SQL query to create your list of fieldnames on the fly.

Comment: Yup!  On the other hand, if you don't know them beforehand, then you're necessarily updating the **entire** table... in which case you may as well set them all to zero first and then loop through the $_POST array.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the replies: Have kind of got it working using your code, but it only updates the first result, no others. Code below: `$newQuery=mysql_query("select * from ispdfs where assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'");
  $newResult=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery); 

  foreach ($newResult as $showPP_ids) {
    $val = (int) isset($_POST['showPP_ids']); 
    mysql_query("UPDATE ispdfs SET showPP = $val WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($showPP_ids));
  }`

Comment: Yes, because awm's solution doesn't go through the fields of `$_POST['showPP_ids']`. @awm: You can make your code example perfect by testing if `$nothing` is an array -> if yes, loop it. @all: This is still not ideal. I would collect the necessary updates (e.g. with concat into the query string) and perform the mysql_query not in the loop but afterwards = only once.

Comment: Not sure I'm following... Are you saying that I need to wrap my above code in `if (isset($_POST['linkTitle_ids'])) { `  or just `if ($_POST['linkTitle_ids']) {`?

Comment: What exactly is `$_POST['showPP_ids']`?  If it's a comma-separated list of checkbox ids, then use my first solution with `$allids = explode(',',$_POST['showPP_ids'])`.  It'll work right out of the box.

Comment: `$_POST['showPP_ids']` is the array of checkboxes. Still can't get this to work properyly : (

Comment: Well there's your problem.  `$_POST` is always an array of strings, which means `$_POST['showPP_ids']` is a string.  Put a `print_r($_POST['showPP_ids'])` in your code and see what you get.

Answer (score 2):

1. Probably your checkbox value doesn't get sent when it's not checked. Confirm this by `print_r($_POST)` in your php code.
   Because of this, your condition

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['showPP_ids'])) {  
       foreach ($_POST['showPP_ids'] as $showPPId) {
   ```

   will never find a checkbox that wasn't checked.
2. As awm says correctly (+1 to that), you don't set the field `showPP` to `0`. Do this:

   ```
   $ppsql=mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = '0' WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($showPPId));
   ```

   when you want to set your sql field to 0.
3. Since your checkbox won't be sent when it's not checked, you need to have some more information on which checkboxes to expect.

   - You could do (reusing your query code)

     ```
     $query  = "SELECT * FROM istable WHERE assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'";
     $result = mysql_query($query);              
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
         $found = false;
         foreach($_POST['showPP_ids'] as $showPPId)
         {
             if($showPPId == $row['id'])
             {
                 // checkbox found
                 $found = true;
                 break;
             }
         }
         $ppsql=mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = '"
                            .($found ? '1' : '0')
                            ."' WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($showPPId));                          
     }
     ```
   - An alternative would be JavaScript: Provide either two checkboxes and set the "not"-checkbox to true if the other one gets unchecked *or* use an `<input type="hidden">` and change its value when the checkbox gets changed. If you have questions to this method, leave a comment - I've used that some times before...

---

**another approach**
Staying with your code, you *could* use this simple approach (but please don't...):

```
// first, set all fields to zero
/* long version
$query  = "SELECT * FROM istable WHERE assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);              
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {                                           
         $ppsql=mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = '0' WHERE id = ".$row['id']);
    } 
*/
// or short version:
$ppsql=mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = 0");

// now, update these rows that appear in `$_POST['showPP_ids']`
// (using the code you provided)
if (isset($_POST['showPP_ids'])) {  
    foreach ($_POST['showPP_ids'] as $showPPId) {                   
        $ppsql=mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = '1' WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($showPPId));                          
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, but not quite... `isset($_POST['showPP_ids'])` will always evaluate to true.

Comment: The first six lines of "another approach" do this:  `update istable set showPP=0`.  No need for a loop.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies, much appreciated. Had a go with the code you provided but couldn't get any of it to work : ( Have kind of got awm's working, (see edit). S