# PHP/MySQL Update checkbox selection to database 2

Tags: php, mysql

Following on from a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017118/php-mysql-update-checkbox-selection-to-database), I'm trying to update a database field with a 1 or 0, depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

It seems to work when the checkbox is checked but not when empty.

Any ideas how to solve this? Code below. Many Thanks, S.

Here's the code within my form:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM istable WHERE assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);              
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {                                           
        echo '<li>                          
                <label for="changePP'.$row['id'].'"><input id="changePP'.$row['id'].'" type="checkbox" name="showPP_ids[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"'.($row['showPP']=='1' ? ' checked="checked"':NULL).' /> Display</label>
                </li>'. PHP_EOL;                                        
        }
```

And the php process code (updated):

```
$newQuery=mysql_query("select * from istable where assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'");
    $newResult=mysql_fetch_array($newQuery);    

    foreach ($newResult as $showPP_ids) {
      $val = (int) isset($_POST['showPP_ids']); 
        mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = $val WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($showPP_ids));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code can work this way for you... the thing is that if you don't tick a checkbox on page, its value is not being submitted with the form data and therefore you are unable to set **showPP** to **0** in your database

I have 2 possible solutions in mind:

if all records **other than** the ones ticked on page should be set to 0, you can do it this way:

```
$values = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $showPP_ids));
mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = 1 WHERE id IN('$values')");
mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = 0 WHERE id NOT IN('$values')");
```

---

another solution would be to store all the IDs in **hidden field(s)** on HTML page with that form and check which of them you're getting in $showPP_ids array - those will be set to 1 - and which of them are missing from that variable - those will be set to 0

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM istable WHERE assocProp = '".$_POST['id']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);              
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<li>                          
            <label for="changePP'.$row['id'].'">
                <input id="changePP'.$row['id'].'" type="checkbox" name="showPP_ids[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"'.($row['showPP']=='1' ? ' checked="checked"':NULL).' /> Display
            </label>
            <input type="hidden" name="original_ids[]" value="'.$row['id'].'" />
          </li>'. PHP_EOL;
}
```

... and in the PHP file (no MySQL SELECT is neccessary here at all):

```
foreach ($_POST['original_ids'] as $id) {
    if (isset($_POST['showPP_ids']) && in_array($id, $_POST['showPP_ids'])) {
        $val = 1;
    } else {
        $val = 0;
    }
    mysql_query("UPDATE istable SET showPP = $val WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($id));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The first option works great but affects all of my database entries, when only two may be on a page at any one time. The second option I can't seem to get working... S

Comment: sorry, I've used multidimensional array check in the foreach statement, which was wrong... replaced by in_array() call, it should work now

Answer (score 3):

```
$val = (int) isset($_POST['showPP_ids']);
```

Is an Array. It should be

```
foreach ($newResult as $showPP_ids) {  
$val = (int) isset($_POST['showPP_ids'][$showPP_ids]);
```

I guess

Answer (score 0):

When a checkBox is not checked, the value isn't submitted to the server.Pls

Please use `isset($_POST['id'])` to check if the value exists.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

You are testing whether the array $_POST['showPP_ids'] is set, which it always will be.

I think your test should be:

```
$val = (int) isset($_POST['showPP_ids'][$showPP_ids]);
```