# How do I create a PHP "edit" form for this page so users can edit their choices?

Tags: php, html

I understand how to include the database connection in the beginning and how to send this information to the database.

My problem is retrieving the information for an edit, including the checkboxes with the value as "array" in the db.(might be a separate issue on its own)

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="a php page" method="post">
 <center>First Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="FirstName"><br />
 <center>Last Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="LastName"><br />
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <p>
 How many Things?
 <select name="Things">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 </p>
 <br/>
 <center>Stuff<br />
 Yes<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="Stuff"><br />
 No<input type="radio" value="No" name="Stuff"></center>
 <br />
 <br />
 Extras<br />
 <center>
 <input type="checkbox" name="Extras[]" value="E1" />Peppers<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="Extras[]" value="E2" />Onions<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="Extras[]" value="E3" />Lettuce<br />
 </center>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 Others?
 <select name="Stuff">
 <option value="That">That</option>
 <option value="Third">Third</option>
 </select>
 </p>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Click to Submit Order" />
 <center
 </form>

 <center> <the server">Click Here for Orders<center>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does this post help <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997252/get-post-from-multiple-checkboxes>

Answer (score 0):

to send information  `SET` ; to get informations from database is `SELECT` , to edit informations in database is `UPDATE`

Comment: That, I understand. But is there any kind of reference for the syntax in updating check boxes? It seems that this is only found in other languages and I can find no such solution to this in PHP.

Comment: have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017118/php-mysql-update-checkbox-selection-to-database) it will help u